# How to analyze a common pattern in Flak code?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am studying python Flask.
There is a common patten written in several sampl code.
But I can't figure it out.
I think no matter it is a POST or GET request, it will be directed to the function index and both of them will go through the same route and get the same result which is render_template("index.html", form=form, name=name) and name=None and form is newly created object and its form.validate_on_submit() is false.
I don't know how to analyze it. Please clue me.

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"]) 
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ""
    return render_template("index.html", form=form, name=name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right-- both a `GET` or `POST` to `/` will be processed by that route-- the difference is really how the browser accesses the page.

What `form.validate_on_submit()` means is "If this is a POST request and all the validation is good, do this..."

So when you first load the `/` webpage by typing in `http://localhost:5000/` in your browser, your browser will `GET` the page, and load it.  So the `form.validate_on_submit()` will return `False` (since it's a `GET` request) and the `name` value will be `None`.

When you then fill in the form (which is assumed to be `<form method="post">`) and hit submit, the same route will get loaded, but this time with a `POST` request-- so the `form.validate_on_submit()` will now be `True` (assuming the form is valid) and the value of `name` will now be whatever was provided in the `name` form field.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree with you partly. When the post request is sent to bask-end after the GET request, the received request is routed to / and the variable form is assigned again therefore it is a brand new variable just like the one in GET request case, isn't it? This is the point I can't get over.

Comment: When a POST request is recieved-- first the `name` variable will be `None` (same as if it were a GET request) but then it gets reassigned to the data from the form `name=form.name.data` because that logic branch is now `True`.

Comment: The part I can't figure out is that when the POST request is received,  from is reassigned and how come form.validate_on_submit() can be TRUE?

Comment: Ahh, I see your confusion-- `form = NameForm()` does a little magic in the background, by default it's populated by the request data, so `form = NameForm()` is the same as `form = NameForm(formdata=request.form)` so when a form isn't sent-- the 'blank' form is created, but when a POST request is received it's filled in by provided values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know where to trace this code? Thank you again.

Comment: Sure-- https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/9b029c379cfda2a7463cf771f933a1c425b4ce16/flask_wtf/form.py#L24